# MySQL crashes ("Some pointers may be invalid and cause the dump to abort")

Tags: mysql, database, xampp, corrupt

I have a 5GB MySQL database called "tweets", from which I need to access the table "searchresults". But when I perform a query on it or create a dump, the MySQL Server (Running on Windows 10) crashes all the time with the same error at the same row.

For example, if I try to dump the database with the following command:

```
C:\xampp\mysql\bin>mysqldump.exe --user root --force tweets > D:\secondtry.sql
```

I get the following error message in the cmd.exe window with the exact same row over and over again:

```
mysqldump.exe: Error 2013: Lost connection to MySQL server during query when dumping table `searchresults` at row: 5222907

mysqldump.exe: Couldn't execute 'SELECT engine FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES WHERE table_name = 'stats'': MySQL server has gone away (2006)

mysqldump.exe: Couldn't execute 'SET SQL_QUOTE_SHOW_CREATE=1': MySQL server has gone away (2006)

mysqldump.exe: Couldn't execute 'SELECT `COLUMN_NAME` AS `Field`, `COLUMN_TYPE` AS `Type`, `IS_NULLABLE` AS `Null`, `COLUMN_KEY` AS `Key`, `COLUMN_DEFAULT` AS `Default`, `EXTRA` AS `Extra`, `COLUMN_COMMENT` AS `Comment` FROM `INFORMATION_SCHEMA`.`COLUMNS` WHERE TABLE_SCHEMA = 'tweets' AND TABLE_NAME = 'stats'': MySQL server has gone away (2006)

mysqldump.exe: Couldn't execute 'UNLOCK TABLES': MySQL server has gone away (2006)
```

and in the mysql_error.log I receive the following message and the server shuts down:

```
Server version: 10.1.8-MariaDB <br/> key_buffer_size=16777216 <br/> read_buffer_size=262144 <br/> max_used_connections=1 <br/>  max_threads=1001 <br/> thread_count=1 <br/> It is possible that mysqld could use up to <br/> key_buffer_size + (read_buffer_size + sort_buffer_size)*max_threads = <br/> 787099 K  bytes of memory Hope that's ok; if not, decrease some <br/> variables in the equation. 

Thread pointer: 0x0x5b93168 <br/> Attempting backtrace. You can use the <br/> following information to find out where mysqld died. If you see no <br/> messages after this, something went terribly wrong... <br/> mysqld.exe!my_parameter_handler() <br/> mysqld.exe!my_mb_ctype_mb()<br/> mysqld.exe!??0Global_read_lock@@QAE@XZ()<br/> mysqld.exe!??0Global_read_lock@@QAE@XZ()<br/> mysqld.exe!?store_record_for_lookup@Stat_table@@IAEXXZ()<br/> mysqld.exe!??0Global_read_lock@@QAE@XZ()<br/> mysqld.exe!??0Global_read_lock@@QAE@XZ()<br/> mysqld.exe!??0Global_read_lock@@QAE@XZ()<br/> mysqld.exe!?store_record_for_lookup@Stat_table@@IAEXXZ()<br/> mysqld.exe!?store_record_for_lookup@Stat_table@@IAEXXZ()<br/> mysqld.exe!?ha_rnd_next@handler@@QAEHPAE@Z()<br/> mysqld.exe!?rr_sequential@@YAHPAUREAD_RECORD@@@Z()<br/> mysqld.exe!?sub_select@@YA? AW4enum_nested_loop_state@@PAVJOIN@@PAUst_join_table@@_N@Z() <br/> mysqld.exe!?setup_end_select_func@@YAP6A?AW4enum_nested_loop_state@@PAVJOIN@@PAUst_join_table@@_N@Z0@Z() <br/> mysqld.exe!?exec_inner@JOIN@@QAEXXZ() <br/> mysqld.exe!?exec@JOIN@@QAEXXZ()<br/> mysqld.exe!?handle_select@@YA_NPAVTHD@@PAULEX@@PAVselect_result@@K@Z()<br/> mysqld.exe!??0Table_scope_and_contents_source_st@@QAE@ABU0@@Z()<br/> mysqld.exe!?mysql_execute_command@@YAHPAVTHD@@@Z()<br/> mysqld.exe!?mysql_parse@@YAXPAVTHD@@PADIPAVParser_state@@@Z()<br/> mysqld.exe!?dispatch_command@@YA_NW4enum_server_command@@PAVTHD@@PADI@Z()<br/> mysqld.exe!?do_command@@YA_NPAVTHD@@@Z()<br/> mysqld.exe!?threadpool_process_request@@YAHPAVTHD@@@Z()<br/> mysqld.exe!?tp_end@@YAXXZ() <br/> KERNEL32.DLL!SetUserGeoID()<br/> ntdll.dll!TpSimpleTryPost() <br/> ntdll.dll!EtwNotificationRegister()<br/> KERNEL32.DLL!BaseThreadInitThunk()<br/> ntdll.dll!RtlUnicodeStringToInteger()<br/> ntdll.dll!RtlUnicodeStringToInteger()<br/>

Trying to get some variables. Some pointers may be invalid and cause<br/> the dump to abort. Query (0x5b9a908): SELECT /*!40001 SQL_NO_CACHE */<br/>
* FROM `searchresults`  <br/> Connection ID (thread ID): 2  <br/> Status: NOT_KILLED<br/>
```

So far I have tried :

1. I set innodb_force_recovery in the my.ini to 1 and 6
2. I used the parameters "--force", "--skip-extended-insert" and "--hex-blob" for the mysqldump.exe
3. I used PHPMyAdmin, MySQLWorkbench and even tried the Microsoft SQL Migration Tool to convert the DataBase into a MSSQL database
4. I increased the max_allowed_packet option in the my.ini
5. I used an Hex Editor to find the corrupt row in the .idb file to delete it, but I could not find out what I have to delete
6. Use my backup, but the error is already in there
7. "Repair Table", but I get the following response "The storage engine for the table doesn't support repair"
8. Rebuilt the table with "ALTER TABLE searchresults ENGINE = InnoDB;" but the error occurs during the rebuild.
9. Setting the innodb_log_file_size parameter in the my.ini to the maximum of 4G throws the same error.
10. Use a different computer

I am pretty sure that there is a corrupt dataset in row 5222907 or 5222908 and that is why the server crashes. It would be totally fine for me to lose one row, if I can access the rest of the data afterwards. I could even lose the first 5222908 rows. But when I can't delete the corrupt data. If I use the query

```
DELETE FROM searchresults LIMIT 5222908
```

The server crashes again.

I would be very thankful for any tips on this matter. The data is very important to me, because I need it for my Master Thesis, which is due very soon.

Thank you for your time and effort!

EDIT: This is my table structure (notice, there are no keys or indexes):

```
CREATE TABLE `searchresults` (
 `id` bigint(20) DEFAULT NULL,
 `user` varchar(50) CHARACTER SET latin1 DEFAULT NULL,
 `createdAt` timestamp NULL DEFAULT NULL,
 `retweetcount` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
 `favoritecount` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
 `message` varchar(500) CHARACTER SET latin1 DEFAULT NULL
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1 COLLATE=latin1_german1_ci
```

EDIT: I used an INSERT INTO like this:

```
SELECT id INTO OUTFILE 'C:/Temp/allCount.csv' FIELDS TERMINATED BY ','
OPTIONALLY ENCLOSED BY '"' LINES TERMINATED BY '\n' FROM searchresults;
```

And depending on the column I select (id, retweetcount etc.) I get a different amount of rows. They are always lower than 5222907, but this means, the issue could still be something parameter related instead of a corruption error. What do you think? Do you know some additional parameters I could adjust in the mysql config?

Comment: Take a look at MySQL's "REPAIR TABLE ..." command. It is well documented.

Comment: repair the table. if that doesn't work, you'll have to start from scratch, and also start keeping better backups.

Comment: I forgot to mention that. I also tried "Repair Table", but I get the following response "The storage engine for the table doesn't support repair".

Comment: Shut down server, make a copy of your whole data directory to be able to get back to it. Better late then never. Maybe you already experience a read error here, then your hdd might be broken. Restart. Do you have an index on that table? Are you able to access the data before the row in question? (e.g. `select * from searchresult limit 10`)? Do you know the primary key of the row in question? Are you able to access data after the problematic row  (e.g. `select * from searchresults where id = <some id really after the broken row>?

Comment: I have no index or primary key on the table. I can access the data with a "limit" restrictor. But when I try to access data that is behind the "broken" row like "SELECT * FROM `searchresults` LIMIT 14000000,1" the server crashes.

Answer (score 0):

You could look into modifying these properties of mysql server:

nano /etc/mysql/my.cnf

```
query_cache_size=16M
key_buffer_size=256M
```

Or maybe even try increasing the allowable execution time for the query from mysql client:

```
SET GLOBAL MAX_STATEMENT_TIME=1000;
```

before you execute your query.

Comment: None of the three options makes a difference. I don't think that it is a storage problem. I guess it is probably a data corruption problem!